# Entity with orphanRemoval not being dropped

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a set entities such as:

```
public class EntityToDrop {

    @NaturalId
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private ParentEntity parentEntity;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "entityToDrop", cascade = {CascadeType.REMOVE, CascadeType.REFRESH}, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<OtherEntity> otherEntities= new HashSet<>();

    [...] (other fields and relationships)
}

public class ParentEntity {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parentEntity", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<EntityToDrop> childEntities = new HashSet<>();

    [...]
}

public class OtherEntity{

    @ManyToOne(optional = true,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @NaturalId
    private EntityToDrop entityToDrop;
    [...]
}
```

In some part of the code I'm calling

```
parentEntityInstance.getChildEntities().remove(entityToDrop);
[...]
entityManager.persist(parentEntityInstance);
```

Which I expect should always remove `entityToDrop` from the database, since it's marked with `orphanRemoval`. However, when the relationship with `OtherEntity` exists it's not getting removed, and more interestingly, if I remove the relationship with `OtherEntity` then try to remove it from the `ParentEntity` in the same transaction, it's not getting dropped either.

Is there any case where `orphanRemoval = true` will not work as I expect it to? And as a followup how would I figure out what's stopping my entity from being removed in this case?

Comment: after you `remove` shouldn't you persist those changes?

Comment: It's possible that my minimum example is not completely valid. I've tried to summarize the issue as much as I can, but one of the issues I'm having is that I don't know how to completely reduce it.

Comment: @Eugene I'm doing other (unrelated) changes to `parentEntity` and persisting in the end, but yeah I'll add it to the question.

Comment: I honestly don't know (or have the time to debug now), all I can do it +1 in hopes someone will help you more

Comment: `persist(parentEntityInstance)` means you're adding an all-new entity, not editing one. To edit one, first fetch it with `em.find(Entity.class, id)`, then change it's data, then `em.flush()` for good measure so as to not delay any errors that may occur in the database. You can also use `em.merge(entity)` to update it, but with `persist` you're always trying to add a new one, and all it's children (if they have Cascade.PERSIST or Cascade.ALL).